# How to call a function repeatedly at fixed intervals using Android Service?

Tags: android, service, notifications, onstart

Here's my code i want to call that log again and again, after fixed interval but some how there is some problem.

```
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
       super.onStart(intent, startId);  
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Log.i(tag, "Service started...");

       Handler handler = new Handler(); 
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
               Log.i(tag, "Post Delayed Function"); 
            } 
       }, 2000); 

   }
```

Comment: "some how there is some problem." would you mind being a little more specific?

Comment: All i want to do is, i want to push a notification on ceratin action.. currently the problem i am facing is onStart calls only one time.. i want to call function repeatedly.

Comment: yes, onStart is called when you, like, start the service. depending on how your service is declared, it can auto stop or it may need to stop itself afterward

Comment: But what i understand from service is it runs in the background and i want to trigger a function from background (from Service). Is there is any method to override or anything i am missing ?

Comment: it doesn't run in the background. it runs without UI. what function do you want to trigger, and what doesn't work in your code?

Comment: so i guess AsyncTask is the right solution for me to go ? i am not so very sure.